# What is the list of valid GWT DOM / consumed events for Cells?

Tags: dom, gwt, right-click

I've run into this multiple times, and can't find anything comprehensive.  I want to know the complete list of all valid consumable DOM events for GWT.

The [GWT docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/index.html) for NativeEvent says:

```
public final java.lang.String getType()
Gets the enumerated type of this event.
Returns:
the event's enumerated type
```

Where is this enumeration?  Does it actually exist?  The actual code used (that I've found) that explicitly says these events always uses strings: "click", "contextmenu", "mouseup", "dblclick", etc.  (etc covers so many vaguaries ...)

I'm trying to implement both Double Click and Right Click for cells in a CellTable ala [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/8ff1c5f3932a8679/d04e148f675dfef1?lnk=gst&q=celltable+double#d04e148f675dfef1).  I'm passing super("click", "contextmenu", "mouseup", "dblclick"); in the constructor of my extension of AbstractCell.  Then I overrode onBrowserEvent:

```
@Override

    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, ImageProperties<T> value,
            NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<ImageProperties<T>> valueUpdater) {
        if (event.getButton() == NativeEvent.BUTTON_RIGHT) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            eventBus.fireEvent(new RightClickEvent<Context>(context, event));
        } else {
            super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
        }
    }
```

However, I run into two issues.  One, the default contextMenu still gets shown (over my custom one) - not to mention it doesn't even use the DOM event type.  A different problem, how do I check if its a double click event?  I find it hard to believe that it's literally an arbitrary set of strings ...

Thanks in advance!
John

Comment: The solution to the double click is: 
if(event.getType().equals("dblclick"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native JavaScript DOM event types [really are arbitrary strings](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) and support for a given event type (and the name thereof) can be browser dependent.

Answer (score 3):

the enumeration you are looking for **does exist** in the [BrowserEvents class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/BrowserEvents.html). you should use those constants instead of “magic” string literals.

Comment: after all, you are using GWT because you don’t want to bother yourself with browser quirks, amirite? ;)